# How to remove all punctuations from string except those in decimal numbers in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

Input is the code I'm using, Output is the output I'm getting, required output is the output I want.

Input:

```
import regex as re  
keyword = 'Auto: tab suspender 2.0 pro'
keyword = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','', keyword)
words = re.findall('\w+', keyword)
print(keyword)
print(len(words))
words
```

Output:

```
Auto tab suspender 20 pro
5
['Auto', 'tab', 'suspender', '20', 'pro']
```

Required Output:

```
Auto tab suspender 2.0 pro
5
['Auto', 'tab', 'suspender', '2.0', 'pro']
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `re.findall` here:

```py
keyword = 'Auto: tab suspender 2.0 pro'
matches = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\w+', keyword)
print(matches)  # ['Auto', 'tab', 'suspender', '2.0', 'pro']
```

The regex pattern used here first attempts to match an integer or float, and that failing will look for words:

- `\d+` match an integer
- `(?:\.\d+)?` or maybe a float
- `|` OR
- `\w+` match a word